# passing eval to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, eval, numeric

I am trying to pass this eval to javascript but keep on getting the following error:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="btnPDf" onclick='<%# "openLink( " +   Eval("ID" )  +  "  );" %>' runat="server" />
```

the error in firebug:

```
Timestamp: 12/11/2012 17:59:16
Error: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
Line: 1, Column: 24
Source Code:
openLink( b690d0c5-9269-424a-ac57-02f3359c982f );
```

I have tried passing it with double quotes and back slashes like '\' but still no joy

Comment: "I have tried passing it with double quotes" - was it like this: `onclick='<%# "openLink(\"" +   Eval("ID" )  +  "\" );" %>'`?

Comment: You're showing us the "pre-rendered" code and the "post-rendered" error... can you show us the "post-rendered" code?  (I.e. the code the browser has received?

Comment: @freefaller This, `openLink( b690d0c5-9269-424a-ac57-02f3359c982f );`, sounds like post-render code )

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you should be able to do this: `onclick='<%# Eval("ID", "openLink(\"{0}\");") %>'`

Comment: Issue #1, JavaScript does not belong in inline attributes. Issue #2, using another language to build JavaScript is a bad idea. Issue #3, you forgot to quote the `Eval("ID")` value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your string concatenation is broken. You need to wrap your parameter in quotes using escape sequences -

```
onclick='<%# "openLink(\"" + Eval("ID" ) + "\" );" %>'
```